# concat functions with html strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to write some functions in JS which returns different html elements (e.g. button, input, select, textarea) which i want to use in several forms.
I would like to be able to pass a function to the function which gets called in the returned html when the user interacts with an element.
e.g.: a button

```
// I'm using ES6 syntax

const button = (button_id, button_text, on_click) => {
  return '<button id="' + button_id + '" type="button" onclick="' + on_click + '">' + button_text + '</button>'
}

button("im_the_button_id", "I'm a button", () => { console.log('clicked') })

// Looks like this in the browser:
// <button type="button" onclick="function () {
//        console.log('clicked');
//      }">I'm a button</button>
```

So far so good, the returned html shows up in my form and looks ok to me (noob), when i inspect the button.
But if i click the button i get an
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (                         (index):1`
in the console.
I was concerned that it would make trouble to concatenate a string with a function, so my questions are:
Is this even possible?
Or do i have to pass an id to every element and inject an onClick or onChange function with `getElementyById()` to the element i'd like to render in my form?

Comment: You can not concat a function to a string.

Comment: Create a proper element and use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: You may want to take a look at a framework like reactjs. I'd say your question is a good example of the XY problem. While you can't concatenate functions with strings, there are other ways to accomplish your actual goal (adding event listeners to elements without a ton of boilerplate).

Comment: You aren't allowed to define a function in an element attribute. You can only call functions there.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, you could probably concat on_click.toString(), but, IMHO, you'd be better off using document.createElement("button") and assigning it properties that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your button method expects three params. When you call it, your second param should be the third param. You forgot to pass the button ID (first param).

Other than that, use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you feel more comfortable using a string to create your button instead of a DOM element as Aerik suggested you could do something like this

```js
const button = (button_id,button_text,on_click) => {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<button id="${button_id}" type="button" >${button_text}</button>`;

    var btn = div.childNodes[0];
    // You would like your button to be cross browser compatible.
    if (btn.addEventListener) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', on_click, false); // modern browsers
    } else if (btn.attachEvent) {
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', on_click); // old IE
    }

    return btn;
}

let myBtn = button("im_a_button_id", "I'm a button", () => {
    console.log('clicked')
});

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(myBtn);
```